# How to compute the probabilities of discrete distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

$$F_X(x)=\begin{cases} 0,    \quad \quad \quad \quad x<-1 , \\ \\ \frac{x}{4} +1/4,  \ \   −1 ≤ x < 0 \\ \\ \frac12 ,\ \ \ \ \  \quad \quad 0 ≤ x < 1 \\ \\
\frac{x}{12}+\frac{7}{12}, \ \quad 1 ≤ x < 2 \\  \\1, \ \ \ \ \ \quad \quad 2≤ x \end{cases}$$

Here's the solution to it which i don't understand how to derive:

[image]

I'm not sure how to compute these discrete probabilities, since I'm confused how to calculate the value of $x$. Could you please hint me?

Comment: Your question lacks proper context. Also what the hell are those $t$s? Or were they meant to be $1$s? Please improve your question so others may understand your problem and help you.

Comment: what context exactly? Those t's are some variables you calculate, which add up the distribution to 1. So, i'm not sure how to construct my equations with the t's

Comment: @ThePoorJew I agree to Victor that the distribution looks not well defined. For instance this here: $t/4+1/4 , −1 ≤ x < 0,$  Let´s say $x=-0.5$ Now we have the problem that we cannot input the value into $t/4+1/4$ since there is no $x$. Also it is written $F_X(x)=...$. No $t$ is mentioned here.

Comment: @callculus  Here is the question and solution to it. hope it is more clear now

Comment: Now what is your question? Which part you don´t understand?

Comment: @callculus Where do these t's go? How do we compute these probabilities, if we have these t's? Sorry if this question is stupid.. I am really confused, can't seem to find an explanation in notes nor on internet

Comment: As we said, we are not very happy with that notation. Just imagine that $t$ is replaced by $x$. Is then comprehensible that $P(X< 1)=0.5$

Comment: @callculus okay, i guess there's a typo in the question. If t is supposed to be x, could you hint how to find x then.

Comment: Which x? It depends...

Comment: @callculus well, how I have understood, you have to find the value of small x, in order to find P(X<...), am I right?

Comment: @callculus and no, I don't comprehend why we derive P(X<1)= 0.5 if we replaced t by x.

Comment: The main fact is that for any $y<x$, $P(X \in (y,x])=F_X(x)-F_X(y)$. A related consequence is that for any $x$, $P(X=x)=\lim_{y \to x^-} P(X \in (y,x])=F_X(x)-\lim_{y \to x^-} F_X(y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you have to check the conditions that the cdf is right-continuous.  For instance, $P(X< 1)=\frac12$. This can be read off directly from the cdf. And $P(X\leq 1)=\frac{1}{12}+\frac{7}{12}=\frac{8}{12}$ Thus there is a gap of $\frac{8}{12}-\frac12=\frac16$. And this probability corresponds to $P(X=1)$.

For continuous, discrete and mixed distributions  we have the following relations:

- $P(a\leq X\leq b)=P(X\leq b)-P(X<a)$
- $P(X>c)=1-P(X\leq c)$

I hope these hints help you to comprehend the solution.

Comment: I am wondering if, when you say "t" (there is NO "t" in the formula) you are not referring to the "+" in "$\frac{1}{2_+}$".

Comment: @user247327 in the unedited version of the question there was a typo